# Coverage of sequence between products and sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

$$\prod^\infty_{k=1} {1 + r_k \over 2 \sqrt r_k} < \infty, 0 < r_k \leq 1$$
Show that
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1} {(1-r_k)^2} < \infty $$
My thought:
$$\prod^\infty_{k=1} {1 + r_k \over 2 \sqrt r_k} =\prod^\infty_{k=1} {(1 + \frac{(1 - \sqrt r_k)^2} {2 \sqrt r_k})} < \infty, 0 < r_k \leq 1$$
Show
$$\sum^\infty_{k=1} {\frac{(1 - \sqrt r_k)^2} {2 \sqrt r_k}} < \infty$$
But I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: Convergence of $\prod (1+c_n)$ implies convergence of $\sum c_n$ for any sequence of positive numbers $(c_n)$. So we have $\sum ({1 + r_k \over 2 \sqrt r_k}-1)<\infty$. Now use the following : $(1-r)^{2} \leq 8 \frac {(1-\sqrt r )^{2}} {2\sqrt r}$ for $0<r<1$. [This last inequality is easy to prove if you do some simple algebraic manipulation first].